# How to downgrade Terraform from Version 12 to 11 in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm using Google CLoud Console to run terraform Scrit, I found that Cloud shell is already equiped with Terrafrom version 12.. My Google resources is only supported for Terraform version 11.. How do I downgrade Terraform from Version 12 to 11 in Google CLoud Shell

Answer (score 2):

running all terraform commands in container `hashicorp/terraform:0.11.14`, that's what I am doing currently for old project. so it has no chance to upgrade terraform version any more in container.

```
TERRAFORM_IMAGE=hashicorp/terraform:0.11.14
TERRAFORM_CMD="docker run -ti --rm -w /app -v ${HOME}/.aws:/root/.aws -v ${HOME}/.ssh:/root/.ssh -v `pwd`:/app -w /app ${TERRAFORM_IMAGE}"
${TERRAFORM_CMD} init
${TERRAFORM_CMD} plan
```

Second, make sure you limit the terraform version in your codes. If not, you have the risk to run terraform with higher version (>0.12) and get `tfstate` file upgraded directly. It will be hard to roll back, unless you enable the version control when save `*tfstate` files.

```
terraform {
  required_version = "<= 0.11.14"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to manage your Terraform versions is the tfswitch tool.
You can install it from here: [tfswitch](https://warrensbox.github.io/terraform-switcher/)

**Usage**

```
    |--⫸  tfswitch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Use the arrow keys to navigate: ↓ ↑ → ← 
    ? Select Terraform version: 
      ▸ 0.11.12 *recent
        0.11.13 *recent
        0.11.14 *recent
        0.12.19
    ↓   0.12.18
```

Comment: Did you get it to work painlessly on GCP CloudShell ?